# Why does query (DBAccess) return nil in Id property for the first time?

Tags: ios, swift, dbaccess

I have two classes. The first one is AbstractEntity.swift:

```
class AbstractEntity : DBObject{
    //...
}
```

And another one is User.swift, who inherits AbstractEntity.

```
class User: AbstractEntity {
    dynamic var Sync: NSNumber?
    dynamic var Password: NSString?
    dynamic var id_Worker: NSNumber?
    dynamic var Login: NSString?
}
```

In my main Database Controller I have this method:

```
func getObjectByID(ID: NSNumber, entityClass: AnyClass)-> AbstractEntity{
    println("String value = "+ID.stringValue)
    var query = entityClass.query().whereWithFormat("id = %@", withParameters: [ID.stringValue])

    var resSet = query.fetch()
    var abstractEntity = AbstractEntity()
    if (resSet.count > 0){
        abstractEntity = resSet[0] as! AbstractEntity
    }
    return abstractEntity
}
```

The problem is that when I try to get the object from database by id I have nil in Id value. And it only happens for the first time when I launch my app.

```
var user = getObjectByID(2, entityClass: User.classForCoder())
```

[image]

For the second time I get the correct value:
[image]

Why does this happen?

Comment: Hi, I will have to investigate.  The Id column is missing from the first object but it has been added to the table by the time the second request is made.  It looks like a problem with the schema caching, we will get back to you.  I take it this table is pre-existing and is not created with DBAccess?

Comment: Yes I use the existing table which is not created by DBAccess.

Answer (score 0):

Since these are not DBAccess tables, we need to ensure they are compatible before they are used anywhere.  Although we will log this as a bug and fix it in a future release, you should be able to workaround this by making a call to:

```
+(void)setupTablesFromClasses:(Class)classDecl,...;
```

Which will create the objects, and cache the schemas before they are used.

Thanks
Adrian

Comment: Thank u for the answer. But for some reason DBAccess does not have this method. I see it in the DBAccess.h file in description. But when I type smth like DBAccess.setupTables.. XCode does not suggest me any function. Can you help me how can I call it properly?